# Android app will not run

Tags: java, android

So I am trying to run this app I am using to learn about threads and intents however the app will not run, But I don't have any warning/error underlines in the code, could anyone help me please.

Manifest code:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.learn.tam.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.learn.tam.StartingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

and Activity code

```
package com.example.learn.tam;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Thread timer = new Thread(){

        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
Intent openStartingPoint = new   Intent("com.example.learn.tam.StartingPoint"); 
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    };

    timer.start();
}



}
```

any help would be appreciated please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

to

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Since your app is probably not shown on the home screen (the `MAIN` category is needed).

And also change

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new   Intent("com.example.learn.tam.StartingPoint"); 
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

to

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new   Intent(Splash.this, StartingPoint.class ); 
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

Since your StartingPoint does not define an Intent-Action with `"com.example.learn.tam.StartingPoint"`

See if that fixes anything.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed all my problems, apparently Im just stupid and changed the wrong intent part from MAIN when coded a second one then deleted it

Comment: @TAM Haha, small mistakes can cause big issues :-) Also, since my answer did solve your issues, you should accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove this:

```
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASH" />
```

And replace it with this:

```
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```